# How to use SCSS embedded in html file?

Tags: html, sass, cdn

I want to use SCSS embedded in html file. Like this:

```
<style type="text/scss">
```

I've heard that there's a transpiler file for TypeScript which could also be used as a cdn. Is there such a thing for SCSS too?

Comment: Just change the filename from .scss to .css.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a client-side script for Sass / SCSS.

But another CSS pre-processor [LESS](https://lesscss.org) has.

With LESS, simply use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="EXAMPLE_FILE.less" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less@4.1.3/dist/less.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use watch sass extension or add watch sass to your package(npm or yarn ...) to compile sass to css and add that main.css file to your html file.